# Appending a div in a div

Tags: javascript, html, function, append

I have this in an HTML page. It's an external script that should add a div to the canvasDiv.
The script works if I append the div in the body. But If I want it to append in the div I added through the function it doesn't seem to work. Where am I wrong?

```js
function AdDiv(divname)
    {
        alert("loaded");
        alert(divname);

        //make a div that will be used for the canvas
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.id = 'placedCanvas';
        iDiv.className = 'placedCanvas';

        //document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
        document.getElementsByTagName(divname).appendChild(iDiv);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="canvasDiv"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pixelvaria.com/wp-content/themes/pixelvaria/js/modelscript.js"></script>
    <script>
       AdDiv("canvasDiv");
    </script>
```

Comment: Just do the AdDiv() call when the document is fully loaded (document-ready event). Not somehwere in between. At this situation the DOM is not fully initialized and can not be modified that easily and use getElementById()

Comment: Use `getElementById` in your case, not `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the wrong Javascript method. You want `getElementById` (since that is what you are passing to `getElementsByTagName`:

```js
function AdDiv(divname)
    {
        alert("loaded");
        alert(divname);

        //make a div that will be used for the canvas
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.id = 'placedCanvas';
        iDiv.className = 'placedCanvas';

        //document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
        document.getElementsById(divname).appendChild(iDiv);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="canvasDiv"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pixelvaria.com/wp-content/themes/pixelvaria/js/modelscript.js"></script>
    <script>
       AdDiv("canvasDiv");
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function AdDiv(divId)
{

    //make a div that will be used for the canvas
    var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
    iDiv.id = 'placedCanvas';
    iDiv.classList.add('placedCanvas');

    //append it to the div with the given ID, not name
    document.getElementById(divId).appendChild(iDiv);
}
```

With this:

```
<div id="canvasDiv"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://pixelvaria.com/wp-content/themes/pixelvaria/js/modelscript.js"></script>
<script>
   window.onload = function () 
   {
       AdDiv("canvasDiv");
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get an Element by its `id`. [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName) (as its name suggests) returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) of Elements having a specific name.

```html
<div id="canvasDiv"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://pixelvaria.com/wp-content/themes/pixelvaria/js/modelscript.js"></script>
<script>
function AdDiv(divname)
{
        alert("loaded");
        alert(divname);

        //make a div that will be used for the canvas
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.id = 'placedCanvas';
        iDiv.className = 'placedCanvas';
        iDiv.textContent = "Div text";

        //document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(iDiv);
        document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(iDiv);
}
AdDiv("canvasDiv");
</script>
```